# Display list Vue Axios with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm new to laravel, axios and vue and I used [this tutorial](http://medium.com/@connorleech/build-a-task-list-with-laravel-5-4-and-vue-2-9be0bba06801) to help make a ToDo list:

I want to tweak the basic tutorial by allowing different users to store and view their tasks. I added new user registration and login, but each user would see everyone's list, not only theirs. So I made a one to many relationship between the User and Task model and added these methods to the models:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
}

class Task extends Model
{
    ...
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I updated TaskController.php and TaskList.vue to display only the active user's tasks, but now in the view no list appears and new tasks can't be added.

Here is the code for the two. Everything is the same as the tutorial, except I commented next to the parts that I added:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
  $user = Auth::user();        //Added by me

  public function index()
  {
      return Task::latest()->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();    //Added by me, 
      //this query returns whats expected in php artisan tinker
      //was previously return Task::latest()->get();
      //I also tried this: return $this->user->tasks->toJSON()
  }
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $this->validate($request, [
          'body' => 'required|max:500'
      ]);

      return Task::create([
                'body' => request('body'),
                'user_id' => $user->id        //Added by me 
              ]);
  }
  public function destroy($id)
  {
      $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
      $task->delete();
      return 204;
  }
}
```

In TaskList.vue

```
<template>
    <div class='row'>
        <h1>My Tasks</h1>
        <h4>New Task</h4>
        <form action="#" @submit.prevent="createTask()">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input v-model="task.body" type="text" name="body" class="form-control" autofocus>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Task</button>
                </span>
            </div>

        </form>
        <h4>All Tasks</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-if='list.length === 0'>There are no tasks yet!</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(task, index) in list">
                 {{ task.body }}
                 <button @click="deleteTask(task.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">Delete</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                list: [],
                task: {
                    id: '',
                    body: '',
                    user_id: ''        ///Added by me
                }
            };
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchTaskList();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchTaskList() {
                axios.get('api/tasks').then((res) => {
                    this.list = res.data;
                });
            },

            createTask() {
                axios.post('api/tasks', this.task)
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.task.body = '';
                        this.task.user_id = '';        ///added by me
                        this.edit = false;
                        this.fetchTaskList();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            },

            deleteTask(id) {
                axios.delete('api/tasks/' + id)
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.fetchTaskList()
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            },
        }
    }
</script>
</script>
```

The app worked until I added the few lines mentioned above. Now nothing shows in the display and no new tasks can be added. I am new to laravel and totally new to axios and vue, but to me it seems like what I added should work. There are no error messages when I run it, it just doesn't produce what I want.

Comment: You cant put `$user = Auth::user();` in `TaskController`, where you placed it. Also your not setting `user_id` to the value of the user in vue.

Comment: actually, the user_id in vue is not required.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't need to add the two lines in Vue? Even when I remove them the the input/display doesn't work

Comment: No as you will have user id serverside in session. Also read other comment. that's why it's not working. enable error reporting.

Comment: check in console Whether you are getting response or not . add this line in fetchTaskList() {console.log(this.list); },

Comment: @Abhishek  `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:893
xhrAdapter @ app.js:727
dispatchRequest @ app.js:31512
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:30966
Axios.(anonymous function) @ app.js:30986
wrap @ app.js:516
createTask @ app.js:43124
boundFn @ app.js:31906
submit @ app.js:43164
invoker @ app.js:33717
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ app.js:33515
app.js:43129 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:918)
    at settle (app.js:31038)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:792)`

Comment: use some Restful api client to check whether your api calls are working or not .Please gone through the link  :https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what alternative can I use for putting AuthUser in the controller?

Comment: Do you see this line `class TaskController extends Controller
{
  $user = Auth::user();`? ... `$user = Auth::user();` like I said it cant go there it **must** go in a method. Your creating a syntax error, hence the 500. https://3v4l.org/SEI4M Enable error reporting and get a decent editor.